# How to connect Heroku Github deployment to a repository that I am collaborating to?

Tags: heroku, heroku-ci

I have a Github repository where I am collaborating. The repository is not under my user. I am able to push to the repsitory, since I am a collaborator.
Is it possible to connect Heroku Github deployment to this Github repository?
Not sure if there are any permissions that repository admin will have to configure in order for me to see the repository on my Heroku repository list.

Comment: Have you tried going into the deployment settings on Heroku? That’s where you turn on auto-deploy. The owner can add you as a collaborator on Heroku, which will give you access.

Comment: Hi @JBallin, I have created Heroku apps. I am the owner of the application on Heroku. Though, I am not the owner of the repositories on Github. I have setup automatic deploy for my other applications(where I was repository owner). But the repositories where I am a collaborating is not showing up in the list on Heroku.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution? I'm struggling with this as well.

Comment: I ended up moving the repository under my account. Github organization are now free for small teams. So, you may create a new organization and move repository there.

Comment: Same problem here